# Nexus 10 NumberPicker slow (weight layout)

Tags: android, performance, numberpicker, nexus-10

If Layout has ListView with NumberPicker in each row, when you scroll ListView, it works really slow! Wow!
I tested on two Nexus-10. First Device work preaty fast, Second slow.

- I thought that's device problem. Branchmark test worked fine on both devices.
- Used [Custom NumberPicker](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker) - nothing, the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found the soution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856882/bad-performance-when-scrolling-on-android-4-3-with-nexus-10#comment29533468_19856882) via `android:layerType="hardware"`